# Opening file object with python: readlines() and readline() does not return any value

Tags: python

I have a problem returning values using readlines() and readline(), but not with read().
Any one knows how this can happen?
Appreciate it

with open('seatninger.txt', 'r') as f: # open within a context manager

```
f_contents = f.read()

f_contents_list = f.readlines()

f_contents_line = f.readline()

print(f_contents)

print(f_contents_list)

print(f_contents_line)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code which creates these errors?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I edited my question with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exausted the file with `read`, so you need to go back to *read it again* using [seek](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm):

```
f_contents = f.read()
f.seek(0)
f_contents_list = f.readlines()
f.seek(0)
f_contents_line = f.readline()
```

Python goes through the file, reads data and remembers where it stopped.

When you use `read()` it reads whole file and it stops at the end of the file.

When you use `readlines()` it reads whole file, splits it on newline character and returns the list.

When you use `readline()` it reads and returns **next line**, remembering where it stopped reading, distinguishing lines based on newline character.

Comment: "go back", can you elaborate on that? Don't understand the code you posted

Comment: @LiviuIosif When you do `f.read()`, python navigates through the whole of the file object, finishing at the end, so that it can return to you the contents of the file. You need to go back to the beginning if you want to do anymore reading.

Comment: I've tried to hash tag they others and take each in a row

Comment: I see. So I just f_contents = f.read()
f.seek(0)
f_contents_list = f.readlines()
f.seek(0)
f_contents_line = f.readline()

Comment: Don't know how to go back at the beginning

Comment: @LiviuIosif I've added a bit more description to what happens.